# My program does not print the correct output

Tags: c++, input

When I run this program and enter "1" on woodtype and "S" on the size, "try again appears. what could be the problem?

ps. the input for Wood Type are 1,2,3
input for size are S,L

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int woodType;
    int L;
    int S;
    int size;
    
    
    cout<<"Furniture Company\n \n1 - Pine\n2 - Oak\n3 - Mahogany\n "<<endl;
    cout<<"Wood Type: ";
    cin>>woodType;
    cout<<"Size: ";
    cin>>size;
    
    if (woodType == 1 & size == L){
        cout<<"Price: $110";
    }
    else if (woodType == 1 & size == S){
        cout<<"Fine: $100";
    }
    else if (woodType == 2 & size == L){
        cout<<"Price: $247.5";
    }
    else if (woodType == 2 & size == S){
        cout<<"Price: $225";
    }
    else if (woodType == 3 & size == L){
        cout<<"Price: $341";
    }
    else if (woodType == 3 & size == S){
        cout<<"Price: $310";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Try Again.";
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `&&` operator as the logical conjunction (AND) operation in all of your conditions instead of single `&`.

Comment: I see you have mapped wood type to an integer, meaning 1 = Pine, 2 = Oak, 3 = Mahogany. You should do the same for sizes and compare them to integers like 1 for L and 2 for S. The way you have this written won't work. `L` and `S` are integers that are not initialized, `size` is an integer that you are initializing from user input, so it should take integers too, like 1 or 2, and then you should compare `size` to 1 for Large and 2 or Small.

Comment: Where do you initialize the `S` and `L` variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the description you gave, S and L should be char literals. Right now you're inputting `size` as an `int`, and then comparing it to other uninitialized `int`s. Additionally, as @bloody noted in the comments, you should use `&&` (logical AND) instead of `&` (bitwise AND):

```
int woodType;
char size;


cout<<"Furniture Company\n \n1 - Pine\n2 - Oak\n3 - Mahogany\n "<<endl;
cout<<"Wood Type: ";
cin>>woodType;
cout<<"Size: ";
cin>>size;

if (woodType == 1 && size == 'L'){
    cout<<"Price: $110";
}
else if (woodType == 1 && size == 'S'){
    cout<<"Fine: $100";
}
else if (woodType == 2 && size == 'L'){
    cout<<"Price: $247.5";
}
else if (woodType == 2 && size == 'S'){
    cout<<"Price: $225";
}
else if (woodType == 3 && size == 'L'){
    cout<<"Price: $341";
}
else if (woodType == 3 && size == 'S'){
    cout<<"Price: $310";
}
else{
    cout<<"Try Again.";
}
```